# Ring properties proofs.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove the following properties of a ring R:

(a) For all a,b,c in R we have $a(b-c) = ab -ac$

(b) If R has multiplicative identity 1, then $(-1)(-1) = 1$.

(c) If R has multiplicative identity 1, then for all a in the ring we have $(-1)a = -a$

Attempt: I will use for the following 
axioms for all a,b,c in R

i) $(ab)c = a(bc)$

ii) $a(-b) = -ab$

iii) $a + (-a) = 0$

Proof(a): Suppose a,b,c are in R. Then $a(b-c) = a(b + (-c)) = ab + a(-c) = ab + (-ac) = ab -ac$

Proof (b): 1 is in R, then $(-1)(-1) + (-1) = (-1)[(-1) + (1)] = (-1)(0) = 0$

Proof (c) : Suppose 1 is in R, then $(-1)a = (-1)a + (1)(a) - a = 0 - a = -a$

Please can anyone please verify this are all correct, and if not, can anyone please give some feedback. I would really appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First proof looks good to me.

The second proof shows that $(-1)(-1) + (-1) = 0$. This is *close* to the final conclusion you wish to draw; push it one step further.

The third proof is good, though you elided over a bit in the middle. After the second inequality, you might write:

$$ = (-1 + 1)a - a = 0a - a = 0 - a = -a.$$

Even in the added steps above, it assumes familiarity with the fact that $0a = 0$.

(If this has not been established, use the standard trick of $0a = (0+0)a = 0a + 0a$ and cancel.)

Comment: Could I say (-1)(-1) + (-1) = 0 = (1) + (-1) , which we can cancel (-1) to get to (-1)(-1) = (1)?

Comment: @user3425 Looks good to me! Alternatively, you could just add $1$ to both sides; then $(-1)(-1) + (-1) + 1 = 0 + 1$, whence the left hand side becomes $(-1)(-1) + 0 = (-1)(-1)$, and the right hand side becomes $1$. Either way should be just fine.